# Dynamic button in gridview ASP.NET c#

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have a grid view in Asp.net.  i want to generate button for specific rows.
Like i have a column named as "Status". If status is "Accept" a button should be generated in that particular row.
[column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKEJN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TemplateField` in ASP.NET `GridView` and conditionally set the `Button` visibility, like shown below:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Accept" 
                Visible='<%# Eval("Status")=="Accept" %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: How about this approach?
but its not working as required.


 int count= GV_Borrorwer_Details.Rows.Count;
        
           if (count> 0)
           {
               if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
               {
                   if (e.Row.Cells[9].Text == "Accept")
                   {
                       Button button = new Button();
                       button.Text = "Return";
                       button.ID += 1;
                       e.Row.Cells[13].Controls.Add(button);
                   }
               } 
           }

Comment: Do i need to do some code behind C# ? i mean for checking condition etc?

Comment: In code behind you have to write the usual data binding part for GridView to the data source based on SELECT query. Rgds,

Comment: actually i want to generate button for all the rows. then if a given condition gets true the button gets [disabled] automatically

Comment: The additional condition sounds a bit unclear. I gave you the answer already: you can further modify the solution up to your additional requirements. At this point, I am closing this comments thread: you can accept the answer and post additional questions separately. Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

first add template field button like this

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="status" ShowHeader="False">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server"   CausesValidation="false"
CommandName="Select" Text="button" />
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

and codebehind

```
   protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
     {
         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {
             Button btn = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btn");





             if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text == "Accept")//replace 1 by your column(status) index in gridview
             {

                 btn.Visible = true;
             }

             else
             {

                 btn.Visible = false;

             }

         }
     }
```

and to add code to this button so add it on

```
     protected void grid_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
     {

  //code
   }
```